# AttributeError: 'StringField' object has no attribute 'content'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am relatively new to Python and I've been following the Miguel Grinberg Flask Mega-Tutorial.

I have a very simple form which, when I try to submit, I receive the following error:
**AttributeError: 'StringField' object has no attribute 'content'**

Here is the form.py

```
class WeiboForm(FlaskForm):
''' 微博表单 '''
content = StringField(label='微博内容：',
                      validators=[DataRequired("请输入微博内容")],
                      description="请输入微博内容",
                      render_kw={"required": "required", "class": "form-controal"})
submit = SubmitField(
    label='发布',)


def validate_content(self,field):
    """限制微博文字长度"""
    content = field.content
    if len(content) < 5:
        raise ValidationError("长度不能小于5个字")
    if len(content) > 140:
        raise ValidationError("长度不能大于140个字")
    return content

def publish(self,user,db):
    """ 发送微博 """
    data=self.data
    #创建对象
    weibo=Weibo(
        content=data['content'],
        user_id=user.id,
        is_valid=datetime.new(),
        created_at=datetime.new()
    )
    db.session.add(weibo)
    db.session.commit()
    return weibo
```

Here is views.py

```
@app.route('/home/weibo',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def weibo_publish():

''' 发布微博 '''
form=WeiboForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    #新增记录
    form.publish(user=current_user)
    #提示用户
    flash('发布成功')
    #跳转
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
return render_template('/home/weibo.html',form=form)
```

Here is templates

```
{% block content %}
<div class="contanier">

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<form class="form-weibo" role="form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('weibo_publish') }}">
    <div class="form-inner clearfix">
        <div class="form-header clearfix">
            <span class="pull-left">有什么新鲜事告诉大家？</span>
            <span class="pull-right">已输入21字</span>
        </div>
        {{ form.content }}
        <ul class="text-danger">
        {% for err in form.content.errors %}
        <li>{{ err }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="pull-right">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.submit }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

It took me four hours. It was really hard.
Please help me find the reason

Comment: Please include the full traceback. And indent the code samples in your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
content = field.content
```

do

```
content = field.data
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. The problem has been solved